# Liquibase looks for "db-changelog.xml" file even when the --changeLogFile option refers to the different file

Tags: java, liquibase, liquibase-cli

I have observed a very strange behaviour when running Liquibase command (with `liquibase.exe` tool) from CMD terminal, on Windows.

I have a project, that's structured as:

```
my_project
|-src
  |-main
    |-java
    |-resources
      |-db-with-sample-data.xml
    |-webapp
  |-test
    |-java
```

Now, if I'm in the `my_project` folder and I run:

```
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --classpath="C:\mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar" --changeLogFile="src\main\resources\db-with-sample-data.xml" --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" --username=user --password=password update
```

I get:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: The file db-changelog.xml was not found in the configured search path:
    - C:\projects\my_project
    - ...(other default paths)
```

and if I run:

```
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --classpath="C:\mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar" --changeLogFile="sr\main\resources\db-with-sample-data.xml" --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" --username=user --password=password update
```

(**pay attention!** I changed `src` to `sr`)

then I get:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: The file sr\main\resources\db-with-sample-data.xml was not found in the configured search path:
    - C:\projects\my_project
    - ...(other default paths)
```

Ok, I see, that `Liquibse`, by default, looks for the `--changeLogFile` value **relative to the folder** I run it (because I see where it's looking for for the --changeLogFile value after every run of the liquibase.exe command).

But, why in the first case it reports, it could not find `db-changelog.xml` and in the second one (when I just removed one letter `c`) - it then properly parses the `--changeLogFile` value?

Comment: Use / instead of \ as a path separator. Even on Windows.

Comment: Does src\main\resources\db-with-sample-data.xml have an include or reference to "db-changelog.xml"?

Comment: @PJatLiquibase yes..